# MySQL connection via terminal failing

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, command-line, terminal

Hi I am using Linux/Ubuntu and I am having a problem on logging in on mysql

when I run the code:

> sudo mysql -h localhost -u root -p

I got an error that says:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/obitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

How can I fix this?

I am using:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.22, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2
rails 3.2.3
ruby 1.9.3
```

Please help

Comment: Is your MySQL instance set up to bind to localhost or is it bound to your host's network IP address?

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, but How do I know if it is bind to localhost or not?

Comment: Check the 'bind-address' variable in '/etc/mysql/my.cnf' if it's not set to 127.0.0.1 connecting to local host won't work, connect to whatever IP it is set to there instead (which is likely the address that eth0 is set to).

Answer (score 0):

First you can try to see if it is running at all with command

`ps aux | grep mysql`

Mysqld should be there.

Check also if listening address, because it might be your outside address instead of localhost with command:

`netstat -antp |grep mysql`

Then check your config file to see where exactly your socket file is being written. After that you have verified that it's up and running you can try to connect to it with command

`mysql -u root -p -S /path/to/socket.file`

It's possible that you have socket file on other place and because of it you can't connect to server. `-h localhost` is not needed if you are connecting to localhost because it's assumed if `-h` is not used that you are connecting locally but it might be needed if your listening IP address is external one and not internal (127.0.0.1 for localhost or 0.0.0.0 for all addresses).